# Accessing a file through JSON object?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, path

I have some paths in a react file that look like this:

```
import azureIcon from './azure.png';
import dropboxIcon from './dropbox.png';
```

I also have a separate JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "azure",
      "description": "blah blah",
      "icon": "azureIcon"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "dropbox",
      "description": "blah blah",
      "icon": "dropboxIcon"

    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to have it identify the variable like this? Or will it not work because currently the value of "icon" is set to a string value? What would be a good way to approach this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do this directly, but you could do something like

```
const icons = { azureIcon, dropboxIcon };

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => (
        /*or w/e the correct way to normally render it is*/
        <img src={icons[post.icon]} />  
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to place images in public accessible folder. Here is [example](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) from create-react-app docs section in case you use it.

So to simplify your code you can use such approach:

1. Place icons in **public** accessible folder (let`s say we have icons folder inside)
2. Update your config

```js
const posts = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "azure",
      "description": "blah blah",
      "icon": "azure.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "dropbox",
      "description": "blah blah",
      "icon": "dropbox.png"

    }
]
```

3. Show icons in such manner

```js
const Component = (posts) => (
    <React.Fragment>
       {posts.map(post => <img 
           key={post.id} 
           src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/icons/${post.icon}`} 
       />}
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have to use icons as images I would choose [the way @Kison suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60571686/10887120).But it is nice if you could font awesome, here it is showed how to install/import font awesome https://fontawesome.com/start and you can search icon here https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery and all you have to do is paste the website says html code it is like following:
`<i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>` this will render azure icon and 
`<i class="fab fa-dropbox"></i>` this will render dropbox icon.

Here these are two icons' links:
(azure icon) https://fontawesome.com/icons/accusoft?style=brands
(dropbox icon) https://fontawesome.com/icons/dropbox?style=brands